# Lebesgue integral of sequences of functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Having a problem with this part of Measure Theory on how to set up the problem and understanding the path to the solution.

#

a)  Assume that $f_n \in L^1(\mathbb{R}, \mu)$ and $f_n \rightarrow 0$ almost everywhere, as $n\rightarrow \infty$ Prove,

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin(f_n(x))e^{-x^2}d\mu(x) = 0
$$
*For the above, I understand that if $g_n = \sin(f_n(x))e^{-x^2}$ then $g_n \rightarrow 0 $ but how to use this for whole space $\mathbb{R}$? The theorems that I have only works finite E.*

b) Calculate

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{\sin^n(x^2)}{x^2}\right)d\mu(x)
$$
if it exists. 
*Here I don't see any convergence a sequence.*

c) Consider the sequence of functions 
$$f_n(x) = e^{-n^4x^2}\cos^2(n\pi x)$$
and then the sequence of their sums 
$$
s_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)
$$
Prove that $s(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)$ is integrable and that 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} s_n(x)dx \rightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}}s(x)dx
$$
as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: The key is the dominated convergence theorem. If $f_n \to f$ a.s. and there exists an integrable function $g\in L^1$ s.t. $\sup_n |f| \le g$, then $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$ and you can exchange limit with integration. Try to find the right dominating function and prove a.s. convergence.

Comment: but $sin^n(x^2)$ does not converge to any function a.s. and for the first one, I do see that it converges to 0 inside but the theorem that allows me to say the integral is 0 is for a finite set E how do I extend to whole space?

Comment: $|\sin(x^2)|\le 1$, so for $x$ s.t. $|\sin(x^2)|<1$ it's $n$th power converges to 0. $\sin(x^2)=\pm1$ has a countable number of solutions, so as long as $\mu$ is s.t. it maps any countable set to zero, you can say that $\sin^n(x^2)\to 0$ $\mu-a.s.$. If $f_n$ converges to $0$ a.s. then $\sin(f_n)$ converges to 0 as well. Could you state the theorem you have to use and the assumptions on $\mu$?

Comment: I don't have a stated theorem to use and all the given information is there but yes, $\sin^n(x^2)$ is bounded by $\pm 1$. The issue is that to use L.B.D.C.T, one needs to have a convergent series no?